# Is there a way to get Concordion test results output into pdf format?

Tags: java, concordion

By default the concordion framework records test results into html format. Is there any extension or way to get it create a pdf instead? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of currently. You could try using a library like [openhtmltopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) to convert the output html to pdf. If you do this, please let us know, we may be able to add it in as an optional extension.